# Nodejs How to copy multiple files into one

Tags: node.js

I have about three files and I'm saving them as strings in three variables. I would like to concatenate those strings and save them to a file. The problem is the computer doesn't wait to get done reading those files before it executes the write function and by then it's late. I tries using the callbacks and counting the files. Am I doing this the right way or is there a better way that is more simple?

```
var 
    start = Date.now();
    header = "",
    content = "",
    footer = "",
    html = "",
    filesLoaded = 0,
    fileTotal = 3,
    fs = require('fs'),
    getFileContent = function(filePath) {
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                filesLoaded++;
                if(filesLoaded >= fileTotal)
                    console.log(Date.now() - start);
                return data;
            }
        });
    },
    writeIndex = function() { 
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(filesLoaded >= fileTotal) {
                html = header + content + footer;
                console.log(html);
                fs.writeFile('index.html', html, function(err) {
                    console.log("file not written:e" + err);
                });
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 10);
    }

header = getFileContent('header.html');
content = getFileContent('content.html');
footer = getFileContent('footer.html');

writeIndex();
```

Comment: How about you show us your code so that we can see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation in JS is easy:

```
var combinedString = string1 + string2 + string3
```

Writing Strings to files is easy as well

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {    
  if (err) throw err;     
  console.log('It\'s saved!');    
});
```

Now replace *hello world* with the `combinedString` and you have it

Comment: What if string1, string2, and string3 haven't loaded yet? That is where the real fun is lol.

Comment: Then you have to post some code. Where are you loading the strings from?

Comment: The strings are being loaded from html files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but it works. The problem was when I returned the data in the callback it would not update my variable. So I put the file names in an array in the order I wanted them to be read. First header.html, then content.html, and footer.html. So I guess I what I did was callback chaining. Where the callback would call a recursive function and read the next file. When it reached the total it would write the file and return the function killing the recursive function. But I would like to make the code more understandable. It seems a little messy to me.

```
var
    startTime = Date.now();
    html = "",
    includes = ["header.html","content.html","footer.html"],
    filesLoaded = 0,
    fileTotal = 3,
    fs = require('fs'),
    compileFile = function() {
        fs.readFile(includes[filesLoaded], 'utf8', function readFileResponse(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                html += data;
                filesLoaded++;
                if(filesLoaded >= fileTotal) {
                    writeIndex();
                    return;
                }
                compileFile();
            }
        });
    },
    writeIndex = function() {
            console.log(html);
            fs.writeFile('index.html', html, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("file not written: " + err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Compiled file in " + String(Date.now() - startTime) + "ms");
                }
            });
    }

compileFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var files = ['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'];
var outStream = fs.createWriteStream('outfile.txt');
for (file in files)
   fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(outStream);
```